# Python problems with codecademy and IDLE

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I have done this challenge on codecademy.

```
def spam():
    eggs = 12
    return eggs

print spam()
```

This works on codecademy but if I put it in IDLE and run it I get an error saying invalid syntax. So I am a bit contused about what is happening. Can any one help.

http://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-python-6WeG3/1/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096

Comment: Check for the version of python you are working on. It should an issue in python3.0

Comment: Coursera has a couple courses on Python 3.x if you're interested - Codecademy is still teaching 2.x (which is still popular amongst a lot of Python programmers and worth learning the differences of - but not the most recent version).

Comment: (You could also install Python 2.7 if you're learning Python 2; a lot of the good learning material does still teach this version, and it's still very widely used. In a perfect world everyone would move to Python 3.4 immediately, but... it's not a perfect world.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDLE is most likely running it using Python 3, where print() is a function. The below code should fix it.

```
def spam():
    eggs = 12
    return eggs

print(spam())
```

Comment: Thanks that emplanes it.

Answer (score 1):

You must be running IDLE for Python 3.x, in which [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is no longer a statement but a function.  Thus, you need to call it as such:

```
def spam():
    eggs = 12
    return eggs

print(spam())
```

Your code worked in CodeAcademy because they are using Python 2.x.